# Changing button's size based on its content's length, so the button keeps its shape

Tags: uibutton, interface-builder, constraints

I have a `UIButton` which is created programmatically (it can be customised from `Interface Builder`, though). It is a circular and it looks like this:

[image]

Now I'm working on Internationalization and I need to check it for Double-Length Pseudolanguage. The image above is taken when the app language is set to double-length pseudo, but as you can see, the button only shows one word. Here are the constraints of the button:

[image]

The title style of the button is plain, its text is centre-aligned, and the line break is set to "Word Wrap".
How to make the button keep its shape but to increase its size when needed (basically, to increase its width and height for the same amount, so it keeps being a circle), so for example, in this case to show two "Menu" words? If you know how to achieve this I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the content compression resistance on the button to required (1000) for horizontal and vertical. It will also depend on the stackViews above and below allowing for the size change.

Comment: Thank you, it works. But I have a question about your answer. By setting the content compression resistance on the button to 1000, we give it a higher priority, so the button's size won't change (it won't become an oval, for example, to fully contain the text), right? So, this means that the text's font size becomes smaller. Is that happening by default or I can have a control over that behaviour?